# sql many-to-many(?) pdo query help needed

Tags: php, sql, pdo

I am trying return rows after joining two tables and I am having a hard time getting the result I want.  I have two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `all_sessions` (
    `session_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `type` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'TBA',
    `breakoutsessions` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `location` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'TBD',
    `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Title',
    `details` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'TBA',
  PRIMARY KEY (`session_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `session_id_UNIQUE` (`session_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=8 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

session_id  type  breakoutsessions  location  title  details
----------  ----  ----------------  --------  -----  -----------------
1           lect  1,3,4             bld1      ph1    details text here
2           tour  2                 bld15     ph2    details text here
3           soci  6                 bld3      ph3    details text here          
4           lect  1,2               bld2      ph3    details text here
5           lect  6                 bld3      ph3    details text here
```

AND

```
CREATE TABLE `break_sess_pair` (
    `pri_key` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `session_id` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    `breakout_id` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`pri_key`),
  UNIQUE KEY `pri_key_UNIQUE` (`pri_key`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=11 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

pri_key  session_id  breakout_id
-------  ----------  -----------
1        1           1          
2        1           3
3        1           4          
4        2           2
5        3           6          
6        4           1
7        4           2          
8        5           6
```

I tried simply joining the tables but that doesnt seem to work, I end up with nulls.  This is the code that is returning nulls in all fields except session_id and  breakout_id

```
function manytable(){
  $dbcon = dbConnect::getInstance();
  $stmt = $dbcon->db->prepare("
    SELECT
      *
    FROM `all_sessions`
    RIGHT JOIN `break_sess_pair`
    ON 'break_sess_pair.session_id'='all_sessions.session_id'
  ");
  $comp_sessions_list = array();
  if($stmt->execute()){
    $result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    return $result;
  }
}
```

What I am trying to do is combine the two so that I wold end up with something like this:

```
session_id  type  location  title  details            breakout_session
----------  ----  --------  -----  -----------------  ----------------
1           lect  bld1      ph1    details text here  1
1           lect  bld1      ph1    details text here  3
1           lect  bld1      ph1    details text here  4
2           tour  bld15     ph2    details text here  2
3           soci  bld3      ph3    details text here  6        
4           lect  bld2      ph3    details text here  1
4           lect  bld2      ph3    details text here  2
5           lect  bld3      ph3    details text here  6
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT b.session_id, 
a.type, 
a.location, 
a.title, 
a.details, 
b.breakout_session
FROM `all_sessions` as a
INNER JOIN `break_sess_pair` as b
ON 'break_sess_pair.session_id'='all_sessions.session_id'
```

This should work

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, the only thing is I am now getting an empty array returned.  Do I need to change my pdo statement?  It is currently 'fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)'

Comment: Thanks again SunRay, I made a few adjustments and got it to work.  I made sure my sql datatypes were consistent across my tables and changed the ON statement to  ON b.session_id = a.session_id .... which seemed to have done the trick

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who is interested the final working function is:

```
function manytable(){
  $dbcon = dbConnect::getInstance();
  $stmt = $dbcon->db->prepare("
    SELECT 
      b.session_id,
      a.type,
      a.location,
      a.title,
      a.details,
      b.breakout_id
    FROM `all_sessions` AS a
    INNER JOIN `break_sess_pair` AS b
    ON b.session_id = a.session_id
  ");
  if($stmt->execute()){
    $result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    return $result;
  }
}
```